# L2TP VPN fails to connect - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, vpn

I'm using the built-in VPN client (under Settings, More networks, VPN) on a Galaxy S4 (GT-I9500) running Omega v17 (Android 4.3).

I set up an L2TP (PSK) VPN connection and try to connect. It says "connecting..." for a while and then just says "disconnected" without any error message whatsoever. How do I tell what's wrong? Is there any kind of log somewhere?

I can see in the server logs that it does try to connect, but nothing in there gives me any clue as to why it disconnects. A PPTP VPN connection to the same machine works fine.